# SPSS converting a string into a numeric variable issue

Tags: string, variables, spss

I have a string variable with lots of parentheses and other punctuation e.g. _LSC Debt licensed work. How can I easily convert it to a numeric variable when I already have a specified code list for it? i.e. I don't want it to automatically recode everything because it uses the wrong values against the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataset with two variables: a string holding the current messy name and a numeric variable  holding the new code.  Then, with both the original dataset and the lookup one sorted by the string, do MATCH FILES specifying a table match (or use Data > Merge Files > Add Variables).

Comment: I keep getting errors when I try to enter the numeric variable's value labels in of: Value labels The (ADD) VALUE LABELS command included a symbol other than a value where a value (either numeric or string) was expected.  For compatibility with previous systems, a parenthesized value would have been acceptable.  All value labels up to the next slash will be ignored.

Comment: @Rachael, this is a separate problem, please post it in a new question. In that question please post a sample of your data and corresponding syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a separate file which includes two variables:
- one contains each of the possible values in the original string variable to be recoded (make sure the name and width are the same as your original variable)
- the second contains the new values you want to recode **to**.

when you set this up, match the files like this:

```
get file="filepath\Your_Value_Table.sav".
sort cases by YourOriginalVarName.
dataset name ValTab.
get file="filepath\Your_Original_File.sav".
sort cases by YourOriginalVarName.
match files /file=* /table=ValTab /by YourOriginalVarName.
exe.
```

At this point your original file will contain a new variable that has the codes you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In general I agree with the solution provided by others. However, I would like to suggest an extra step, which could make your look-up file (see the answer of eli-k and JKP) a bit better.

The point is that your string variable with lots of parentheses and other punctuation probably also has different ways to write the same thing.
For example:
_LSC Debt licensed work
LSC Debt licensed work
_LSC Debt Licensed Work
etc.
You could create a lookup-table with three variables: the unique values of the original string variable, a cleaned-up version of that variable, and finally the numeric value you want to attach.
The advantage of the cleaned-up version is that you can identify more easily the same value although it is written differently.

You could clean up using several functions:

```
string CleanedUpVersion (A40).
compute CleanedUpVersion = REPLACE(RTIM(LTRIM(UPCASE(YourOriginalVarName))),'_',''). 
execute.
```

In this basic example we convert to capital letters, delete leading and trailing blanks and remove the underscore by replacing it by nothing. 
Overall this could help to avoid giving different numbers to unique values in your original variable that mean the same thing, while you would like them to have the same number.